# AVFoundation to overlay an alpha channel video on another video?

Tags: ios, video, overlay, avfoundation

I have tried to overlay an image on a video asset and also thought of there should be some way to overlay an alpha channel video on another video.

Is there any way to overlay an alpha channel video on another video asset?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20812353/ios-overlaying-alpha-channel-video-on-another-video