# Inserting users camera feed into IOS app

Tags: ios, video-streaming, avfoundation

There's a music video app on IOS that turns on the user's camera and plays a video.  While the video is playing the user's face is inserted into the video at certain intervals (on a billboard, on a poster, etc..).

How are they doing this?  Plugins?  I have been going through the AVFoundation framework and can't find anything close to tackling this and am starting to go insane.

The app is the same as the web link below if you want a quick demo (your face appears within the first 20 seconds on her phone then a t-shirt right after).

https://cantgetenoughofmyself.webcam/

Comment: If you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Also, be sure to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Well, my problem is figuring out where to start as I mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's clever, but conceptually straight forward.

At it's simplest, this is basically two videos, the "music video" with an alpha channel (transparency) where the second video is placed underneath and shows through.

You can do this with AVFoundation, but it's not a simple one step process.

Look into how to composite two videos with AVFoundation - something like this [Overlay Two Videos with AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515955/overlay-two-videos-with-avfoundation)

That will at least get you the basics.  Almost certainly this is done with frame by frame compositing, you can look into using CIFilters as well as eventually even writing your own Custom Compositor.

For a very general question, this is a reasonable very general answer I think.

Comment: Thank you, that is what I needed to help me on my path.  I know it was generic, but so is my knowledge at this point :)